# How to detect light polarization?

Tags: arduino, optics

I want to build a proof of concept implementation of the [BB84 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84).

I plan on having an Adruino send a pulse across a fiber optic cable, with a polarizer that it controls. On the other end is an Arduino with polarizer for reading. I'm pretty sure I've seen hardware for everything except the detection part. Does something like this exist?

Comment: Light polarization is a quantum quantity If memory serves. Therefore it cannot be "detected" but it can be "collapsed" into a specific state.

Comment: What baud rate are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not familiar with BB84, but you can buy polarization diverse detectors (basically 4 photodiodes with 2 polarized beamsplitters between them).  These give you the S and P polarization state.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, doing some quantum computation based on Arduino sounds fun, but unrealistic if you are asking me...